# A variable to take on the name the name of array keys

Tags: php, variables

I need to get a variable to be named whatever this array key is, in this case, the array key is only 1 word, so it would be something like; theme, entry or date.

```
$a = implode(array_keys($_GET));
```

In this case, I can get $a to equal theme, entry or date, but how can I get the variable to be called $theme $entry or $date?

Comment: Interestingly, what you're trying to do is rather reminiscent of `register_globals`. (In other words, be careful doing this.)

Comment: Just looked it up, a big giant sign says "deprecated". :)

Comment: What should be the value of those variables? And what do you want to use it for?

Comment: I was trying to use this as a shortcut instead of declaring a page-full of possible variables, when only one can get passed to this page. Instead of `$report=isset($_GET['report'])? $_GET['report']:NULL;`x35 more variables, this seemed like it would be much easier.

Comment: **Do not put `$_*` contents in your global scope automatically** - it is **BAD**! For your purpose, define an array of valid/expected GET vars and create the entries in `$_GET` (or some custom array) if they are unset. Additionally, `extract()` won't help you at all for that purpose since `$something` will still be undefined if it wasn't in `$_GET`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple way to do it

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $$key = $value;

}
```

now if you had `$_GET['id']` you can use

```
echo $id;
```

Comment: Nice use of variable variables.

Comment: I had a feeling I was going to have to use those sneaky guys! They are like Inception, going more and more levels deep.

Comment: You'd better do some sanity checks to prevent this from overriding existing variables though. After all, there's a solid reason why `register_globals` has been deprecated...

Comment: @wimvds you are right, in a live example a condition will be added with something like `isset()` to prevent overwriting

Comment: I like this method the most. The extract still leaves me with an unknown

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
    extract($_GET);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: If you are going to use this horrible method, please use the `EXTR_SKIP` flag so a malicious user cannot overwrite existing vars.